# How to get JSON data from Restful API URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jsp

I want to get Json data offered by 'http://localhost:8080/api/printer?exclude=temperature' [HTTP/1.1].

This is the Json data to be provided.

```
   {
  "state": {
    "text": "Operational",
    "flags": {
      "operational": true,
      "paused": false,
      "printing": false,
      "sdReady": true,
      "error": false,
      "ready": true,
      "closedOrError": false
    }
  }
}
```

The type is 'GET' and Content-Type is 'application/json'

And below is my JSP whole source code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function print_stat(){
     jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      async: false ,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/printer?exclude=temperature&apikey=1234567...',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {
        alert("TEST");
      },
      error : function(x, e) {
          alert('server error occoured');
          if(x.status==0){ alert('0 error'); 
          }else if(x.status==404){ alert('404 error'); 
          }else if(x.status==500){ alert('500 error'); 
          }else if(e=='parsererror'){ alert('Error.nParsing JSON Request failed.'); 
          }else if(e=='timeout'){ alert('Time out.'); 
          }else { alert(x.responseText); }
        }
    });
}
 </script>
 <body>
 <input type="button" onclick="print_stat()" value="test">
 </body>
```

I can't see "TEST" pop-up window.
And nothing happens.

What should I do for getting the data?

Please help me.

Comment: `async: false ,` <-- bad idea

Comment: So there is no error in the developer console?

Comment: did you include jquery? doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Your code works for me with my own url.  What are those dots in your url?

Comment: Is that button in a form that is causing page to reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

**Syntax:**

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: uri,       
    data: jsonStrJson,               
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
       console.log(json);
    }
});
```

**You code should be like this 100% working and tested code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function print_stat(){
     jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      async: false ,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/printer?exclude=temperature&apikey=1234567...',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert("TEST");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error : function(x, e) {
          alert('server error occoured');
          if(x.status==0){ alert('0 error'); 
          }else if(x.status==404){ alert('404 error'); 
          }else if(x.status==500){ alert('500 error'); 
          }else if(e=='parsererror'){ alert('Error.nParsing JSON Request failed.'); 
          }else if(e=='timeout'){ alert('Time out.'); 
          }else { alert(x.responseText); }
        }
    });
}
 </script>
 <body>
 <input type="button" onclick="print_stat()" value="test">
 </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Makes no sense setting contentType header on a GET...there is no request content